# Why this jQuery doesn't work in Codeigniter?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, codeigniter

This jQuery is already tested correctly on an html website, now I need to use it on a Codeigniter setup.

So I have a php page that looks like this:

```
    <head>        
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/css/themes/<?php echo $this->config->item("theme"); ?>/normalize.css" type="text/css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/css/themes/<?php echo $this->config->item("theme"); ?>/component.css" type="text/css" />
        <script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/js/modernizr.custom.js"></script>  
    </head>
        <body>
        <div class="container">
            <!-- Top Navigation -->
            <section class="grid-wrap">
                <ul class="grid swipe-right" id="grid">

            <li><a href="#"><img src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/css/themes/<?php echo $this->config->item("theme"); ?>/images/dummy.png" alt="dummy"><h3>A fantastic title</h3></a></li>
            <!-- etc -->
            </ul>


            </section>

        </div><!-- /container -->
        <script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/js/imagesloaded.pkgd.min.js"></script>
    <script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/js/colorfinder-1.1.js"></script>
    <script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/js/masonry.pkgd.min.js"></script>
    <script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/js/gridScrollFx.js"></script>
    <script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/js/classie.js"></script>
        <script>
            new GridScrollFx( document.getElementById( 'grid' ), {
                viewportFactor : 0.4
            } );
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I don't have any Javascript problem on console, however when I scroll down the **"GridScrollFx"** jQuery doesn't add class "shown" to list items

```
GridScrollFx.prototype._scrollPage = function() {
        var self = this;
        this.items.forEach( function( item ) {
            if( !classie.has( item.el, 'shown' ) && !classie.has( item.el, 'animate' ) && inViewport( item.el, self.options.viewportFactor ) ) {
                ++self.itemsRenderedCount;

                if( !item.curtain ) {
                    classie.add( item.el, 'shown' );
                    return;
                };

                classie.add( item.el, 'animate' );

                // after animation ends add class shown
                var onEndAnimationFn = function( ev ) {
                    if( support.animations ) {
                        this.removeEventListener( animEndEventName, onEndAnimationFn );
                    }
                    classie.remove( item.el, 'animate' );
                    classie.add( item.el, 'shown' );
                };

                if( support.animations ) {
                    item.curtain.addEventListener( animEndEventName, onEndAnimationFn );
                }
                else {
                    onEndAnimationFn();
                }
            }
        });
        this.didScroll = false;
    }
```

And this is the CSS:

```
/* Hover effects */
.grid li.shown:hover h3 {
    color: #fff;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,-30px,0);
    transform: translate3d(0,-30px,0);
}

.grid li.shown:hover > a::before {
    border-width: 14px;
    border-color: #2E3444;
}
.grid li.shown img,
.grid li.shown h3 {
    visibility: visible;
}
```

I took the idea from this [tutorial](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2014/05/15/recreating-the-design-samsung-grid-loading-effect/comment-page-2/#comment-464575). So why on scrolling down all items already loaded are not shown?

Comment: Are you loading or using jquery? I am pretty sure this has nothing to do with jquery or codeigniter.

Comment: @KaiQing I don't have any errors

Comment: ok so start throwing some console.log() lines in there and find out what it is not doing

Comment: @KaiQing what it's not doing is use the js gridscrollfx to add the class "shown" to all items that are already in place but hidden

Comment: Pretty sure that GridScroll isn't a jQuery plugin...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your code (head and body) i did not find any jquery js file included. adding something like this,

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: this is a comment, not an answer. you should delete before you get downvoted

Comment: It's an answer, because he is right, OP hasn't included the jQuery library.